# Automatic reply for whatsapp messages approach

Tags: android, android-notifications, whatsapp

I have seen few applications on play store that supports automatic reply for WhatsApp, I searched the internet to find out the approach, but all I found was this piece of code

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "99********");
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    i.putExtra("sms_body", "Hey!");
    i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(i);
```

It will open the WhatsApp and take you to that particular contact if you have saved and it will paste the given text but it will not send the message.

links

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=horizontstack.autoreplyforwhatsapp.whatsreply

They are accessing the notifications to get the messages. I want to know how they are sending the messages in the background without opening the application. If somebody knows the approach please share here.

Comment: could you achieve this??

Comment: i achieved, see my answer if you still have doubt ping me.

Comment: @MukeshGupta could you tell us how did you achieve it please share if there is any sample project

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did by this:

Step 1: copy all code from [NotificationHelperLibrary](https://github.com/iamrobj/NotificationHelperLibrary) repository.

Step 2: Create Notification Listener Service and put below code in `onNotificationPosted(..)` method:

```java
MyNotifiService.this.cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
Action action = NotificationUtils.getQuickReplyAction(sbn.getNotification(), getPackageName());

if (action != null) {
    Log.i(TAG, "success");
    try {
        action.sendReply(getApplicationContext(), "Hello");
    } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "CRAP " + e.toString());
    }
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "not success");
}
```

[This is](https://github.com/salmankhalid8762/WhatsAppAutoReply3) a basic demo.

Comment: How to get if there are reply action on the notification? this code works but the Action Object always returns null...even if the action can be used to reply to messages...

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of WhatsApp and Android OS, you can reply directly from the notification, this is how the apps are doing that. Probably nothing to do with the code you posted. So, if you want to implement auto-reply, you must deal with the notification, and keep in mind the Android OS version limitation

EDIT: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980078/read-notification-bar-title-message-using-accessibility-service-programmaticall) to read notifications using accesibility services

Comment: Exactly, you need Android 7 (Nougat) or newer

Comment: I've just reminded that you can use accesibility services. Check the link on my updated answer

Comment: thanks for the help, I know how to read the messages from notification bar but the thing is how to send messages to WhatsApp user in the background

Comment: Using the accesibility service too

Comment: @Manojj did you find any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp messages contain the Car Extension. You can use it to get the corresponding PendingIntent that you will need to reply to the message.

```
Bundle extension = NotificationCompat.getExtras(notification).getBundle("android.car.EXTENSIONS");
Bundle conversation = extension.getBundle("car_conversation");
PendingIntent reply = conversation.getParcelable("on_reply");
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer version(>= Android 7 ), we have the ability to reply to notification directly from notificationlistener(i have tested it works for all messaging app with multiple messages from user)

This link will be useful for this=> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369508/how-to-utilize-android-nougats-direct-reply-feature-with-a-notificationlistener?rq=1)

For earlier version, we can get action for notification from wearable notification.
See this for more info :- [link](https://medium.com/@lowcarbrob/how-to-reply-to-android-app-notifications-c09e44da9bdb)

Source code for above post :- [link](https://github.com/iamrobj/NotificationHelperLibrary)

Comment: I will link my sample project also until look at these links @santhosh.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp provides support for android wearables like smart watches. Users can send their reply through these kind of gadgets. So those apps collects the notification by pretending to be a smart wearable and they sends their without even opening the WhatsApp.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31314284)

Answer (score 0):

On Android 7+, get the notification using [NotificationServiceListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService) then check if it has [RemoteInput()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/RemoteInput). Finally try to send the reply on the RemoteInput

[Here is a sample app](https://github.com/fbiego/NotificationReply)

In the NotificationService, the notification is replied if it matches the checks

The notification access permission must be enabled to receive the notifications