# Autoresponse for Line

Tags: android

How to achieve the android line automatically reply message function?
Receiving messages using NotificationListenerService, what you need to do now is to reply to the messenger when you receive the message, and automatically do not touch the screen at all?

The following is the message text to the line, and you want to manually select the object to be transferred.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("line://msg/text/" + text));
startActivity(intent);
```

But I would like to send a message to a specific person manually.

A similar problem is [Automatic reply for whatsapp messages approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788600/automatic-reply-for-whatsapp-messages-approach), but I was going to automatic-reply-for-line not whatsapp.

There are other products seen on this function, but can try all the methods have tried to achieve the function I want ....
So is this possible?

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: Sorry my question may not be clear, I have explained my problem in more detail