# Pro-grammatically Reply to notifications for Whats-app in Android

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, whatsapp

I have an Android application developed, this application receives notifications from NotificationListener, through NotificationListener I'm able to receive notifications for whatsapp and other applications etc.

what I need is, want to reply to any Whatsapp notifications without opening the application in phone - I want to send reply pro-grammatically.

Is it possible in Android ?

Comment: I mean , how the smartwatches like Apple, Samsung galaxy etc are sending reply to notification from smartwatches.
Link for samsung Galaxy -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxyGdTor9g8

Comment: Does anybody have answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the notification has direct reply action. Send the reply on the Remote Input
Check this answer for more info.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73017178/13222541