# Automatic reply in Viber/WhatsApp chat without bots

Tags: api, automation, whatsapp, viber

It is possible to implement automatic reply to messages when somebody has sending message to user? I am already implemented that for Telegram but cant find any solution for Viber and Whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a WhatsApp chatbot using WATI - WhatsApp API provider https://docs.wati.io/.

I  wrote a program using Node.js where on receiving certain words(messages) from the user, the verified WATI number sends a particular message. It can be easily developed with the help of webhooks and express server. You can use various provider such as Twilio to get a verified WhatsApp number and an API.

Reference: https://medium.com/the-andela-way/build-a-whatsapp-bot-in-10-minutes-using-node-js-and-twilio-9869b443bf5e

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful. It runs as an android app and requires Android 7+

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73017178/13222541